Include file in nuget, when multitargeting frameworks
I need to embed specific dll in my nuget package. I know how to do it when my project targets only one framework, but i can't make it work when my project targets 2 frameworks.
I'm using dotnet pack to create my package.
Here is a minimal reproducing case:
First
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="C:\Data\file.dll" >
            <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)\</PackagePath>
            <Pack>true</Pack>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

With this simple project, all is working as expected, i can embed a file.

Second
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="C:\Data\file.dll" >
            <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)\</PackagePath>
            <Pack>true</Pack>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Here, i'm trying to target 2 frameworks, you can see that the file.dll is copied, but in a empty folder.

Third
Finally, my last try end up with none files copied anywhere.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
        <Content Include="C:\Data\file.dll" >
            <PackagePath>lib\net6.0\</PackagePath>
            <Pack>true</Pack>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
        <Content Include="C:\Data\file.dll" >
            <PackagePath>lib\netstandard2.0\</PackagePath>
            <Pack>true</Pack>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


If anyone can help me to embed the dll file in the specified targed folder, i would be grateful.
Thank you.
